Amplify React Sign In Redirect not working as intended
I'm trying to implement a feature where whenever a user logs in, depending on the Cognito attribute of user being either 'user' or 'admin.' they get redirected towards a different interface.
This is my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Authenticator, useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import './App.css';
import './index.css';
import config from './aws-exports.js';
import AdminInterface from './AdminInterface';
import UserInterface from './UserInterface';
import { fetchUserAttributes} from 'aws-amplify/auth';

Amplify.configure(config);

function App() {
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserRole = async () => {
      try {
        const attributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
        const role = attributes.profile; // Adjust the attribute name as per your setup
        setUserRole(role);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user role:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserRole();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <div>
          {userRole !== null ? (
            userRole === 'admin' ? (
              <AdminInterface user={user} signOut={signOut} />
            ) : (
              <UserInterface user={user} signOut={signOut} />
            )
          ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

export default App;

I tried implementing this using a useEffect() function that sets the userRole variable to the profile attribute of the user that logged in. While this does allow the users to get access to different interfaces I need to manually refresh in order for that new interface to show up. Also each login is giving me a message saying Account recovery requires verified contact information which wasn't there before.
pop-up for each login
